# Problem chaining Higher Order Components <Functions are not valid as a React child.>

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, higher-order-components

I created a sample project to demonstrate a problem I have when trying to use two Higher Order Components (hoc) together.

First in isolation (no errors)

================================

The first hoc `withStuff` takes an injected argument and a prop and passes the `sum` to the wrapped component.

```
// withStuff.js
const withStuff = ({argNumber}) => (BaseComponent) => ({propNumber, ...passThroughProps}) => {
  const sum = argNumber+propNumber
  return <BaseComponent sum={sum} {...passThroughProps} />
}

export default withStuff
```

The second hoc `withExtra` takes an injected function and doubles the result, passing `double` to the wrapped component.

```
// withExtra.js
const withExtra = (extraFunction) => (BaseComponent) => ({...passThroughProps}) => {
  const double = 2*extraFunction()
  return <BaseComponent double={double} {...passThroughProps} />
}

export default withExtra
```

This is how a `Base` component would use for instance `withStuff` (all working fine so far).

```
// Base.js
import withStuff from './withStuff'

const Base = ({content, sum}) => <div>{content} -sum:{sum}</div>

export default withStuff({argNumber:2})(Base)
```

=================================

Now comes the problem: trying to use `withExtra` inside `withStuff`:

```
import withExtra from './withExtra'

const withStuff = ({argNumber}) => (BaseComponent) => ({propNumber, ...passThroughProps}) => {
  const sum = argNumber+propNumber
  // this does not work
  return withExtra(()=>sum)(<BaseComponent sum={sum} {...passThroughProps}/>)
}

export default withStuff
```

This returns an error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.
```

Is it because now `withStuff` is returning a hoc function instead of a component? That function returns a component itself, so I cannot see the problem. How to solve this?

NOTE CODESANDBOX HERE: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/snirp/hoc-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passing JSX to `withExtra` not a component, Change `withStuff` like this :

```
const withStuff = ({argNumber}) => (BaseComponent) => ({propNumber, ...passThroughProps}) => {
  const sum = argNumber+propNumber

  // this works
  // return <BaseComponent sum={sum} {...passThroughProps} />

  const WithExtraComponent = withExtra(()=>sum)(BaseComponent);
  return <WithExtraComponent sum={sum} {...passThroughProps}/>


}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hoc-test-pm02u

Comment: Thanks for adding a codesandbox link. I accepted this, but several other answers were just as correct.

Answer (score 2):

`withExtra` is supposed to get a component, so I think this line

`return withExtra(()=>sum)(<BaseComponent sum={sum} {...passThroughProps}/>)`

should either be:

`return withExtra(()=>sum)(BaseComponent)`

or

`return withExtra(()=>sum)(() => <BaseComponent sum={sum} {...passThroughProps}/>)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you passing the `ReactElement` and not the component.

Refer to [`what is JSX`](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) behind the scenes.

Note that if you want to add additional properties to given `ReactElement` you can [use `cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).

```
const withStuff = ({ argNumber }) => BaseComponent => ({
  propNumber,
  ...passThroughProps
}) => {
  const sum = argNumber + propNumber;

  const callback = () => sum;

  // Like so you passing the node which leads to error
  // return withExtra(callback)(<BaseComponent sum={sum} {...passThroughProps}

  // Passing the reference
  return withExtra(callback)(BaseComponent);

  // Passing with additional props
  // return withExtra(callback)(React.cloneElement(BaseComponent, ...));

  // Equivalent
  // const WithExtraProps = withExtra(() => sum)(BaseComponent);
  // return <WithExtraProps sum={sum} {...passThroughProps} />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it:

```
return withExtra(() => sum)(BaseComponent)();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hoc-test-thxh0